# how to upper case document field with pymongo?

Tags: pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I wanted to use `update_many(findQuery,updateQuery)` to update one of the field of documents from lower case to upper case with pymongo. I have the mongo query for the same but I wanted to do it by pymongo. Is there any way I can achieve it?

```
db.collection.find({ "state": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc) {
  db.collection.update(
    { "_id": doc._id },
    { "$set": { "state": doc.state.toUpper() } }
    );   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Equivalant approach in pymongo:

```
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Data setup
db.collection.insert_many([{'state': 'was_lowercase'}, {'randomrecord': 'without state field'}])

# search all matching records
records = db.collection.find({"state": {"$exists": True}})

# loop through and update each record
for doc in records:
    db.collection.update_one({'_id': doc['_id']},
                             {"$set": {"state": doc['state'].upper()}})

# pretty up the results
print(dumps(db.collection.find({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))
```

If using pymongo >= 3.9.0 and mongodb >= 4.2, the update_many can take a pipeline operator:

```
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Data setup
db.collection.insert_many([{'state': 'was_lowercase'}, {'randomrecord': 'without state field'}])

# update using pipeline
db.collection.update_many({"state": {"$exists": True}},
                          [{'$set': {'state': {'$toUpper': '$state'}}}])

# pretty up the results
print(dumps(db.collection.find({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))
```

Either way gives the result:

```
[
    {
        "state": "WAS_LOWERCASE"
    },
    {
        "randomrecord": "without state field"
    }
]
```